# Difference of Dictionary.Add vs Dictionary[key]=value

Tags: c#, .net

What is the difference between the `Dictionary.Add` method and the indexer `Dictionary[key] = value`?

Comment: I came looking because I was concerned that older versions of C# might require the use of .Add() to add elements but apparently not.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

**Add** ->  Adds an item to the dictionary if item already exists in the dictionary an exception will be thrown.

Indexer or `Dictionary[Key]` =>  **Add Or Update**. If the key doesn't exist in the dictionary, a new item will be added. If the key exists then the value will be updated with the new value.

---

`dictionary.add` will add a new item to the dictionary, `dictionary[key]=value` will set a value to an existing entry in the dictionary against a key. If the key is not present then it *(indexer)* will add the item in the dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("Test", "Value1");
dict["OtherKey"] = "Value2"; //Adds a new element in dictionary 
Console.Write(dict["OtherKey"]);
dict["OtherKey"] = "New Value"; // Modify the value of existing element to new value
Console.Write(dict["OtherKey"]);
```

In the above example, in first place `dict["OtherKey"] = "Value2";` will add a new value in the dictionary because it doesn't exist, and in second place it will modify the value to New Value.

Comment: And when the key does not exist in `dictionar[key]=value` ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman, it will add in the dictionary with the new key

Comment: Thaks Habib. but we can add new key with dictionar[newkey]=value. Which one is betten way?

Comment: @rsg, for adding a new item, dictionary.add is much better choice, because it will let you know if the key already exists in the dictionary, Using dictionary[key], will update it if the key exists, otherwise it will add a new one

Comment: An ArgumentException will be thrown if the key already exists when using the Add method.

Answer (score 38):

`Dictionary.Add` throws an exception if the key is already present. `[]` when used for setting an item doesn't (it does if you try to access it for read).

```
x.Add(key, value); // will throw if key already exists or key is null
x[key] = value; // will throw only if key is null
var y = x[key]; // will throw if key doesn't exists or key is null
```

Answer (score 18):

The documentation for [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k.aspx) makes this very clear, I feel:

> You can also use the [`Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2.aspx) property to add new elements by setting the value of a key that does not exist in the `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)`; for example, `myCollection[myKey] = myValue` (in Visual Basic, `myCollection(myKey) = myValue`). However, if the specified key already exists in the `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)`, setting the Item property overwrites the old value. In contrast, the `Add` method throws an exception if a value with the specified key already exists.

(Note that the `Item` property corresponds to the indexer.)

Answer (score 7):

The behavior is identical when the key does not exist in the dictionary: the item will be added in both cases.

The behavior differs when the key already exists.  `dictionary[key] = value` will update the value mapped to the key, while `dictionary.Add(key, value)` will instead throw an ArgumentException.

Answer (score -1):

`dictionary.add` add an item to the dictionary whereas `dictionary[key]=value` assigns a value to an already existing key.

Comment: `dictionary[key]=value` adds the key and value if the key doesn't exist. so its a **Add or update** way